# PlayFramework return absolute url in http instead of httpS?

Tags: java, nginx, playframework, playframework-2.2

I've implemented a project in Play!Framework with NGinx using only https.

Everything works fine, the SSL is well recognized and I can use my app from anywhere but when Play! returns an absolute URL, it's in http, not https.

This is problematic, and I don't know where the problem is.
I tried to start Play with -Dhttps.port=XXXX instead of -Dhttp.port=XXXX but it didn't changed the output of "http" instead of "https".

I'm suspecting an Nginx bad configuration (a parameter I forgot?).
Here's my `sites-enabled/website` config file :

```
proxy_buffering    off;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Scheme "https"; # I also tried $scheme without any luck
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
proxy_http_version 1.1;

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.website.com;
        return      301 https://my.website.com;
}

upstream my-backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9100;
}

server {
    listen               443;
    ssl                  on;
    root                 /var/www/website/errors/;

    # http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ is useful for development testing
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/my.website.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/my.website.com.key;

    # From https://bettercrypto.org/static/applied-crypto-hardening.pdf
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # not possible to do exclusive
    ssl_ciphers 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000; # six months
    # use this only if all subdomains support HTTPS!
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains"

    keepalive_timeout    70;
    server_name my.website.com;

    location / {
        #proxy_pass  http://my-backend;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9100;
    }

    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 502 @maintenance;
    location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /error502.html break;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

**Update**: Here's the code that generate the absolute url :

```
controllers.routes.Pages.loginToken(getToken()).absoluteURL(play.mvc.Http.Context.current().request());
```

Comment: When sending an email with a link to my app.

Comment: Oh sorry. I updated the question to answer your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple overloads for `absoluteURL`. You're using this one:

```
public String absoluteURL(Http.Request request) {
    return absoluteURL(request.secure(), request.host());
}
```

The problem with this is that since you're reverse proxying to Play via nginx, Play is actually receiving all the requests through HTTP, and not HTTPS. This means that `request.secure()` is false, and `absoluteURL` will return a URL containing `http://...`.

Instead, manually set `secure` to `true` in one of the overloads:

```
controllers.routes.Pages.loginToken(getToken()).absoluteURL(play.mvc.Http.Context.current().request(), true);
```

Additionally, what I normally do is have a configuration variable for `secure` so it can generate non-https URLs when developing locally.

In application.conf:

```
application.secure = false # for local dev
```

And in production I add the command line option `-Dapplication.secure=true` when starting the application, to override the value in `application.conf`.

Then generating the URL would look like this:

```
controllers.routes.Pages.loginToken(getToken()).absoluteURL(
    play.mvc.Http.Context.current().request(), 
    play.Play.application().configuration().getBoolean("application.secure", true) // default to true
);
```

Comment: I finally made it with `absoluteURL(play.Play.isProd(), request.host());` but your answer is great, so I accepted it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Play's `request.secure()` supports the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header since 2.3.0, so as long as you've configured everything correctly, `absoluteURL` will return an https URL.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer#Configuring-trusted-proxies

Answer (score 7):

What you actually need is to add the scheme in the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.  None of the `X-Forwarded-*` headers are standard, but the convention (or defacto standard) is to put the scheme in `X-Forwarded-Proto`, and Play has support this since 2.3.0:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1823

So, if you add the following to your nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

And have configured Play to trust the x forwarded headers, by adding this to your `application.conf`:

```
trustxforwarded=true
```

Then `RequestHeader.secure` will return true.

Note that in Play 2.4, we've improved the support dramatically, implementing the full specification for the new standard [`Forwarded` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239), as well as being able to specify which hosts to trust forwarded headers from.

Comment: With Play 2.4, Play configuration seems to done with  play.http.forwarded.trustedProxies & play.http.forwarded.version (more info at [HTTPServer / Configure trusted proxies](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HTTPServer#Configure-trusted-proxies) )